# Call WCF function without naming parameters?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Is it possible to configure a WCF method `HelloWorld(string test){}` to accept posted data without actually specifying the name of the first parameter?

I.E. rather than

```
<s:Body...>
  <HelloWorld...>
   <test>foo</test>
  </HelloWorld>
</s:Body>
```

Send

```
<s:Body...>
  <HelloWorld...>
   foo
  </HelloWorld>
</s:Body>
```

I think its possible by changing the parameter type from `String` to `Stream`, but I'd rather not go there yet.

Comment: I think it's possible by defining URI template for that method HelloWorld(string test){ }

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible, below is the solution from what I understood.

WCF Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "HelloWorld/{test}")]
    string HelloWorld(string test);
}
```

WCF Interface implementation

```
public class Service : IService1
{
    return "Success from Hello World";
}
```

Ajax call from jQuery

```
 $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'json',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       url: baseUrl + '/HelloWorld/TestString',
       success: function (response) {
               alert('Ping reply: ' + response);
       },
       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               var jsonFault = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
               alert('Reason: ' + jsonFault.Reason + '<br />Detail: ' + jsonFault.DetailedInformation);
       }
 });
```

I tried with single parameter. Please explain me more if I am wrong.

Queries welcomed...